# Why does this ldapadd command quit with an "Invalid syntax" error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openldap

I'm very new to openldap but extremely well versed in the linux/unix environment.  I'm trying to setup my very first test openldap environment using the guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-server-postinstall).  I've also read most of the admin guide [here](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html) and I have to admit, it is a lot to take in.

So following the ubuntu basic setup guide I created an ldif file that looks like this:

```
dn: ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: People

dn: ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Groups

dn: cn=engineers,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: engineers
gidNumber: 5000

dn: uid=john,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: john
sn: Doe
givenName: John
cn: John Doe
displayName: John Doe
uidNumber: 10000
gidNumber: 5000
userPassword: johnldap
gecos: John Doe
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/john
```

Whenever I tried to add it using:

```
$ ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W -f add_content.ldif
```

I get the following error:

```
adding new entry "cn=engineers,ou=Groups,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax

adding new entry "uid=john,ou=People,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
    additional info: objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

The results in google for this error don't net any helpful suggestions.  What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you don't have the dash in your domain? That could be causing it...

Comment: @NathanC going to try changing that now...

Comment: @NathanC same thing... my guess is that it can't find `posixGroup`.  How do I query for the available `objectClass`es?

Comment: @NathanC also I don't have this `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/` directory.  I installed openldap from source.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with openldap to answer ...someone else here might be though.

Comment: Where is slapd getting it's configuration?  You're either using `slapd.conf` somewhere, or dynamic configuration in `cn=config` via `slapd.d`.

Comment: @larsks I wish I knew how to answer that question... but I'm too much a noob at this.  I'm modifying the `slapd.conf` located under `/usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf` but there is no `slapd.d` directory anywhere at all

Comment: You just answered the question; it sounds like you're using `slapd.conf`.

Comment: @larsks what is the preferred method of modifying this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is undoubtedly that you need to load the `nis` schema into your LDAP server.  How to do this depends on whether your are using the legacy `slapd.conf` configuration file or the newer dynamic configuration hosted in `cn=config` and backed by a `slapd.d` directory.

### Using `slapd.conf`

You will need to `include` the schema definition in your `slapd.conf` by adding a line along the lines of:

```
include /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
```

This assumes that the `nis.schema` file is located at that path; if not, modify the path appropriately.

You will need to restart `slapd` to activate the new schema.

### Using `slapd.d`

(I'm including this for completeness, although it's not directly relevant to your current configfuration).

To load a schema into `slapd` if you're using the dynamic `cn=config` configuration, you would use `ldapadd`.  Depending on how your ACLs are configured, the command might look like this:

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/nis.ldif
```

This assumes that your running `slapd` has an ACL permitting "peer credentials" authentication to `root`.  If that doesn't work, you would need to provide an appropriate bind DN and password using `-D` and `-W`.

There is no restart required in this case.

Comment: Thank you!  If I downloaded and installed the latest version of `openldap` why wouldn't I be configured to use `slapd.d`?

Comment: Maybe the installer defaults to using the legacy configuration file?  In any case the documentation has instructions for converting from `slapd.conf` to `slapd.d`.

Comment: This answer was very helpful time. I had to add few required schema to make it work for me. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: How did you know it was the nis.schema that was missing and not some other schema?  How did you parse the error?

Comment: The error is complaining about the objectclass for cn=engineers, which is "posixGroup". From this it is relatively easy to figure it out in which schema that objectclass is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this problem while following the [Ubuntu OpenLDAP Server tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html).  Solved it by removing all the trailing whitespace from my rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I just struggled with this error!

Answer (score 1):

I fix it deleting the `file.ldif` that i want to charge in openldap (for example: `data.ldif`) because the text editor `vi` sometimes insert invisible character by error or bug and this affect to your ldif file. So delete it and you create another one and try to upload each statement one by one and check with the command `ldapsearch -x -h nameofyourserver -b “dc=whateveris,dc=com”`, goodbye and i hope to help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but the final error was due to the blank or tab spaces I had left trailing rows within the ldif format file I created. As soon as I removed those, the Organization Units were added without problems.